# How do I subscribe using yii2 and redis?

Tags: node.js, redis, yii2, publish-subscribe

I want to use a method in yii2 controller to subscribe to channel so that I can receive realtime update as a subscribed client. I am using redis pub/sub.

```
public function actionSubscribe(){
        Yii::$app->redis->executeCommand('SUBSCRIBE',
        ['notification'], 
        function($redis, $channel, $message){
                print('I just did it!!!!!!');               
        });
        return true;
}
```

I am also using nodeJs and below is my serverside nodeJs code.
Please what am I doing wrong?

I extracted this section that refused to work from the code.

> ```
>         socket.on("message", function(channel, message) {
>         console.log("New message: " + message + ". In channel: " + channel);
>         socket.emit(channel, message);
>     });
> ```

BELOW IS THE FULL CODE

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var redis = require('redis');

server.listen(8890);

 io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    console.log("new client connected");

    var redisClient = redis.createClient();
    //RedisClient deliberately pegged because I want Yii2 php to do the 
    //subscription to the notification channel; not nodeJs.
    //redisClient.subscribe('notification');

    socket.on("message", function(channel, message) {
        console.log("New message: " + message + ". In channel: " + channel);
        socket.emit(channel, message);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
       // redisClient.quit();
    });

}) ;
```

Comment: Please note that the whole code was working before until I tried to subscribe with yii2 by pegging `redisClient.subscribe('notification')` and introducing `yii2 actionSubscribe()`

Answer (score 1):

Considering the above code I think you should use the `redisClient` in the following code section if you are creating it as

```
**redisClient**.on("message", function(channel, message) {
        console.log("New message: " + message + ". In channel: " + channel);
        socket.emit(channel, message);
    });
```

so that the **actionSubscribe()** using the `redisClient` is used to recive the message